# Import SCSS color variables in Angular component not working

Tags: angular, sass, angular9

I'm creating an Angular 9 app and my folder structure looks like this:

```
| app
  | app.component.ts
  | app.component.html
  | app.component.scss
| assets
  | _colors.scss
```

In the `_colors.scss` file I have two colors defined:

```
$red: #DA0000;
$blue: #1080E1;
```

In the `app.component.scss` I'm importing and using the colors like this:

```
@import '../assets/colors';

.some-class {
  background-color: $blue;
}
```

But this is not working, the color is not applied. And there are no errors. VSCode intellisense helps me with the import path so the path is ok. If I'm trying to use a not defined color like `$black` I get an error so it seems that the import it's working but the color is not applied. What I'm missing here? Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the rule isn't being overwritten somewhere else?

Comment: I'm sure, it's a really small app. In fact, if I change the value `.some-class {
  background-color: blue;
}` it works. But if I use the variable it does not work anymore.

Comment: How about if you use `colors.$blue`?

Comment: Nope, I get a compilation error: _SassError: There is no module with the namespace "colors"._

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz example?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add the following to your project in `angular.json`:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "YOUR_PROJECT_NAME": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "options": {
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": ["src/assets"]
            },
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I recommend not storing it in `assets` but in something like `src/styles` or `src/scss` since `assets` gets published when you build the app. You don't really want people to be able to see/access the raw scss files.

You can then import as follows:

```
@import '_colors';
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but it's not working. I moved the colors file to `src/styles` but no luck either.

Comment: Can you try restarting `ng serve`? It's not triggered by changes to `angular.json`, so you have to manually restart it.

Comment: I did it but same result. The thing is I've always had color variables in older projects and it was always working. I'm wondering if this is an Angular 9 issue...

Comment: It works, thanks for the help. I had put the `stylePreprocessorOptions` wrong. Yesterday, after struggling all day with this problem, I was no longer thinking clearly.